# Using EJS without NodeJS

Tags: java, templates, build, ejs, global

I figured that the latest build release would allow me to use ejs globally without using node so I tried doing so.

Though, when I try to use ejs.renderFile(params...), i get the error:

```
TypeError: exports.fileLoader is not a function
```

Which is just another node module. Is there a way to get around this?

Note: This is the only time we use EJS at my company, so, if not, would you kindly point me in a good direction in how to render .ejs files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: You can create an EJS object by running

```
new EJS({url: some/url/to/file.ejs}).render({dataToPass: data, moreData: secondData});
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another way you can use `render` instead of `renderFile`, and your `ejs file` can be get as string:

```js
// here using jQuery
$.get(you_ejs_file_path).then(function (str, status, xhr) {
    const html = ejs.render(str, your_data)); // str is ejs file 
});
```