# Use ejs or header and footer templates for static hosting with github pages?

Tags: javascript, html, hosting, ejs

I have around 10 html documents that only differ due to one div. Is there any way to make a header and footer document, and link them together for each html document? I have used EJS in the past, so I would prefer using it. I am using github pages to host my site, so I cannot use any backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup! These are called partials in EJS, and you insert them with an `include` function:

```html
<%- include('header') %>

<!-- Main content -->

<%- include('footer') %>
```

EJS will look for them in the local directory. Any parameters you passed into [`app.render`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.render) in your Express route are passed down to partials too.

If you need to re-use partials on the same page with unique data, you can pass them a data object too:

```js
<% msgs.forEach((msg) => { %>
    <%- include('msgPartial', { msg: msg }) %>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: Do I need to include backend for this and create and install node_modules? I cannot use backend if I use github pages.

Comment: You can apparently run EJS in a `<script>` tag, so no backend is needed! Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61100840/using-ejs-without-nodejs) for a starting point.