# Rendering a ejs file clients side

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

Currently trying to work out some ajax on cloning an 'item' template, after each post request im trying to insert a ejs template with the new item's (cloned item's) info, into the main ejs page. But I can't seem to find the correct way, to execute that properly. I've followed the documentations have the front end ejs script.

Currently getting error:
resp is not defined

Item display is the ejs template for the all items
'inventory-scroll-list' is the div with all the items
resp is the newly created/cloned item (mongoose)

```
// cloning item with ajax (need to display new item)
$('.cloneItemButton').click(function () {
    const itemId = $(this).attr('id')
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/item/' + itemId + "/clone",
        success: function (resp) {
            console.log('Item Cloned: ' + resp._id)
            var html = ejs.render('<%- include("/itemDisplay",  { item: resp }); %>')

            $('.inventory-scroll-list').append(html)
        },
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = ejs.render('<%- include("/itemDisplay",  { item: resp }); %>')
```

The resp here is a string and won't work because /itemDisplay is not accessible to the browser.

if the ejs file is small and does not depend on other ejs files then you can directly store the contents of that file in a variable

```
template = 'The entire contents of the ejs file';
var html = ejs.render(template,  { item: resp});
```

Comment: im getting an exports.fileloader is not a function...

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: ejs:1
 >> 1| <%- include("/itemDisplay",  { item: {"_id":"5f3aeed531dfc10588b8724c","name":"Yeezy 350 Zyons","size":"6","purchasedPrice":"339.00","purchasedDate":"2020-08-14","author":"5f2df3b4a3e23336f05a3aef","__v":0} }); %>

exports.fileLoader is not a function

Comment: Try This:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61100840/using-ejs-without-nodejs

Comment: I think the problem is that /itemDisplay is not accesible by the browser

Comment: You can store the contents of itemDisplay.ejs in a variable as a string and use it instead of using the include function

Comment: Or you can define a route in the express app to access itemDisplay.ejs and read it in the browser using $.get

Comment: for the stackover flow link you provided i tried and got 'inventory.js:44 Uncaught ReferenceError: EJS is not defined'

Comment: the itemDisplay.ejs file is in my views directory, and the js file im coding in is in the public>js>itemDisplay.ejs, where public and views are in the same directory. I've tried '../../views/itemDisplay' and './itemDisplay' since my app engine is set to views and ejs, as well as a couple other variations all of which say can not find file expect for '/itemDisplay' which gives me the file loader error.

Comment: how would i store my itemDisplay.ejs into a variable?